# whys my javascript reduce function being skipped?

Tags: javascript, arrays

my last function reducedArr, is being skipped?

when I console.log I get the newArry returned?

why is not executed??

```
const sumAll = function(...args) {
    let newArr = [...args];
    let sortedArr = newArr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    })
    let lastArr = ['']
    for (let i = sortedArr[0]; i < sortedArr[1]; ++i ) {
        lastArr.push(i)
    }
    let reducedArr = lastArr.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    })
    return reducedArr;
    
};

console.log(sumAll(1,4));
```

Comment: Do you want sum from `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` or `1 + 2 + 3` when you say `sumAll(1, 4)`

Comment: The first item of `lastArr` is `''`. Then the script adds the number values `1` to `3`. Thus before getting reduced `lastArr` equals ['', 1, 2, 3]. Because of its first empty string value the array gets reduces via string concatenation to the string value `'123'` ... `'' + 1 + 2 + 3` equals `'123'`

Comment: yes I corrected and its working. I wanted 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10. like you said decpk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write the code more succinct using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> **NOTE:** If you want to add `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` if you say as `1-4` then you can
> replace
>
> ```
> Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => i + start)
> ```

```js
const sumAll = function (a, b) {
  const [start, end] = a > b ? [b, a] : [a, b];
  return Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, i) => i + start)
              .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
};

console.log(sumAll(1, 4));
console.log(sumAll(4, 1));
```

Comment: You can include the `4` here if you add `1` to `end - start` as `length: end - start + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your last `reduce` is still working, it just appends string instead of number because you init `let lastArr = ['']` with a `''` item.

Update it to `let lastArr = []`. You will see the final result.

```js
const sumAll = function(...args) {
    let newArr = [...args];
    let sortedArr = newArr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    })
    let lastArr = []
    for (let i = sortedArr[0]; i < sortedArr[1]; ++i ) {
        lastArr.push(i)
    }
    
    console.log(lastArr);
    let reducedArr = lastArr.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    })
    return reducedArr;
    
};

console.log(sumAll(1,4));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer solved the problem. I have another question if you don't mind. How can i include the 4 to the addition??

Comment: By adding `<=` in `i <= sortedArr[1]`

Comment: perfect. thanks.